# What does this Delphi PAnsiChar code mean?

Tags: file, delphi, byte

We all use Delphi for one project and have for years.
But we have never seen the following syntax used with a PAnsiChar and do not know what it means:

```
buffer       : PAnsiChar
recInstance  : Byte
recX         : smallint
num_info     : integer

// buffer loaded from a file...

num_info := 0;
// next two lines are a mystery
recInstance := Byte(buffer[num_info*5]);
recX := Byte(buffer[num_info*5+1])+256*Byte(buffer[num_info*5+2]);
```

In the debugger it looks like recX is just loading 2 bytes, but the syntax does not seem to match.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`PAnsiChar` has always had the nice property that you can access the `AnsiChar` being pointed at, as well as the following `AnsiChar`s using index notation like an array (of bytes or `AnsiChar`s). That is why it is used here.

These days, in modern versions that have `{$POINTERMATH}`, you would rather use a `PByte` instead, which has the same indexing enabled.

`recInstance` is assigned the byte at offset `numinfo*5`, `recX` is assigned the following two bytes as one single 16 bit value.

In a current version, it could be written like:

```
buffer: PByte;
n: Integer;

...

n := num_info * 5;
recInstance := buffer[n];
recX := buffer[n+1] or (buffer[n+2] shl 8); // together a 16 bit value
```

---

As Remy hinted, you could read all three bytes at once using:

```
type
  PRec = ^TRec;
  TRec = packed record
    Instance: Byte; 
    X: Smallint; // a 16 bit (i.e. 2 byte) signed integer.
  end; // total size: 3 bytes.

var
  MyRec: TRec;

...

  MyRec := PRec(@buffer[num_info * 5])^;
```

The `PRec` cast re-interprets the address returned by `@buffer[num_info * 5]` as a pointer to a `TRec`, then dereferences that (using `^`), and assigns the result to `MyRec`.

In other words, `@buffer[...]` is a pointer, `PRec(...)` turns that into a pointer of type `PRec` and `PRec(...)^` gets the 3 bytes at that pointer, as if it were a `TRec`.

`MyRec.X` is now the same as `recX` and `MyRec.Instance` is now the same as `recInstance` in the original code.

Comment: I would use a `PSmallint` type-cast instead of concatenating the bytes manually: `recX := PSmallint(@buffer[n+1])^;`  Or better, define a packed record and type-cast to that instead: `type PRec = ^TRec; TRec = packed record recInstance: Byte; recX: Smallint; end; ... var buffer: PAnsiChar {or PByte}; rec: TRec; ... rec := PRec(@buffer[num_info*5])^;`

Comment: @Remy: I though of that. But I thought it would not really clarify things, because the `PRec(@buffer[n])^` syntax is IMO even harder to understand for someone who already has problems understanding the use of `PAnsiChar` here. I wanted to keep things as simple as possible.

Comment: Is that offset 'num_info times 5' ?
Since the data type is a pointer, the asterisk is what is throwing everyone off.

Comment: @Remy: I updated the answer with your suggestion. Thanks.

Comment: @AIG: I doubt it throws many people off who know Pascal/Delphi. `*` is *only* used for multiplication. Pointers are declared and used with `^`, not with `*`. This is not C or a C-like language. Your comment is a bit like a Pascal programmer asking why those C people put all their code in comments. ;-)

Answer (score 0):

`Byte()` is just type casting of one-byte size value (AnsiChar here) to Byte type

The last code line forms two-byte variable `recX` from two bytes (not accounting for possible overflow effects though)

```
 int16var = byte1 + 256 * byte2  
 //almost equivalent of
 (byte2 shl 8) or byte1
```